# Bitmap looks heavily tilted when printing with a Bluetooth printer

Tags: java, android, printing, bitmap, bluetooth

I'm trying to print a PDF with a Bluetooth printer, what I'm trying to do is convert the PDF to Bitmap, then the Bitmap to a byte array, and sending it through Bluetooth, so far I've been able to print Bitmap images without issues, but when it comes to the PDF, the printed image looks extremely tilted, it is a really weird result, I tried to convert the PDF to the Bitmap and then saving it as a PNG and the resulting file is looking completely fine, but not the printed version.

Here is the code I use to convert the PDF to Bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap fileToBitmap(File file) {
    try {
        PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
        PdfRenderer.Page page = pdfRenderer.openPage(0);
        int pdfWidth = page.getWidth();
        int pdfHeight = page.getHeight();
        Bitmap pdfBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pdfWidth, pdfHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        page.render(pdfBitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        page.close();
        pdfRenderer.close();
        final Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pdfBitmap.getWidth(), pdfBitmap.getHeight(), pdfBitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(finalBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(pdfBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        return finalBitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using a white bitmap as a background since transparency is not supported.
I have already tried several formulas to try an scale the Bitmap correctly so it fits the paper, with some of them it prints it smaller than the paper so I guess the issue shouldn't be something like the printer scaling it wrongly or something.

Here is a screenshot of how the PNG written in disk looks (It is converted from the bitmap which is converted from the PDF, so the printing should look like it, except it doesn't).
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAYK7.png)

Here is how the Printed PDF looks:
[Printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPHGn.jpg)
You can see the Panda image I took from Google is looking fine.

Here is a closer look. If you look really carefully you can see the PDF is actually being printed, but it looks heavily tilted, in some cases you can even see the logo being printed, but again it looks tilted.
[Closer look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZl8Q.jpg)

Printer Model: Sunmi V1s-G.
Android Version: 6.0
targetSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 21

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a method in the printer's SDK to scale the bitmap and prevent this from happening.
It may be an issue only related to this specific printer model, so this probably won't happen with other printers.